# how to get a screenshot for failure tests with method name of failure test

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

With the listeners how can we solve it.Give me a better solution.I tried using with Listners but it is not giving the method name of failure test, it giving the screenshot name with current method name.for example if a  test is failed in one class i want that class method name only.but it is giving execution method as screen shot name

```
public class Invoke {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void invoking() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "E:\\AK\\Selenium files\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("facebook.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("akdhd")).click();
    }
} 

public class Excecution {
    @Test public static void m() throws Exception { 
        Invoke.invoking(); 
        String val=ExcelDynamic.r("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\facebook.xlsx", "Sheet1", 1, 1); 
        System.out.println(val);
    }
```

This code is in another class

```
    public static void screen(String Filepath) throws Exception {
        TakesScreenshot ts = ((TakesScreenshot) driver);
        File fi = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String img = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName() + ".jpg";
        FileUtils.copyFile(fi, new File(Filepath + img));
    }
}
```

i'm calling this method in execution class so it is printing screenshot name m. But i want output name as invoking for screen shot

Comment: Please share your trial code.

Comment: public class Invoke
{
  public static WebDriver driver;

 public static void invoking() throws Exception
 {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\AK\\Selenium files\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
     driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("akdhd")).click();
  
 }
}

Comment: public class Excecution
{
 @Test
public static void m() throws Exception
{
  Invoke.invoking();
  
  String val=ExcelDynamic.r("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\facebook.xlsx", "Sheet1", 1, 1);
  System.out.println(val);
 This is execution

Comment: I wrote screenshot code in another class

Comment: public static void screen(String Filepath) throws Exception
 {
  TakesScreenshot ts = ((TakesScreenshot)driver);
  File fi=ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
     String img = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName()+".jpg";
     FileUtils.copyFile(fi, new File(Filepath+img));
  
 }

Comment: The screenshot name is saving with the exceution code class method M not with the failure test case Invoking

Comment: If would be appreciate if you can improve your question by adding trial code.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a utility method that returns the calling method name.

```
public static String get_calling_method_name() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();
}
```

Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: i Tried this method also but the name is saving with execution class method name i want to get invoke class method name as screenshot name. I am calling screen shot code  from the Execution class method so it coming only execution method name but i want screenshot name as invoke class method

Comment: I am not getting your context, could you please share the requirement with a code sample. This can be helpful in better understanding. However in the mean time, you can definitely query the stacktrace to get method call stack, and then get the exact method name by the index. Something like getStackTrace()[index]

Answer (score 0):

You may try By this,

To change with first index,

```
String img = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + ".jpg";
```

Hope it will work.